# How to tween/Lerp between two numbers

Tags: tween, mit-scratch, lerp

I want to be able to lerp between two numbers (Actually RGB). Sort of like a slider.
Where 0 = (255,0,0), and 1 = (0,255,0).
Is there any way to code with **without an external library or function?**
Thanks.

Comment: The green channel seems straightforward: divide by 255. Red would be 255 minus green. And blue stays zero. Am I overlooking something? Please share with us any solution you have tried so far. What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, HMMMMMMM *thinks*

Okay, suppose the slider affects a variable called Slider

You could do this:

RGB(255 - (Slider * 255), Slider * 255, 0);

That should do, I think